# Reset Hikari connection pool

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, connection-pooling, hikaricp

We are using Spring Boot app with Hikari connection pool and Hibernate and Oracle. Sometimes in operational environment we see the blow exception:

```
Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

This error repeats until I reset the application and then the error will solved.
I think Hikari state is not updated. I lookedup for a solution for reseting the connection pool without reset the application.

I want to know the root cause the problem and know reset the connection pool is true solution and how to do that?

Comment: Resetting hikari is not the solution. You are leaking connections in your application, which is the issue you need to fix.

Comment: I don't have anywhere in code that work with connections directly. All code in ORM and spring data (Repository interfaces)

Comment: Doesn't matter, there is a leak somewhere, you don't need to work with the connection directly to achieve that. Doing things like `EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager` or using a direct hibernate session could be the cause (or wrong use of the `JdbcTemplate`). Either way there is a leak in your application (I would suggest turning on leak detection on HIkari so you get errors), which need to be fixed. Or you have long running jobs that take up all the connections in the pool (which would require a larger pool).